# Two 5-gons - One with a concave vertex and another with a convex vertex

Tags: geometry, polygons

I don't know if I may ask this question here, but I want someone could make a simple construction by *Mathematica*. Could anyone be able to construct a 5-gon with only one concave vertex and the same 5-gon with the reflection of the concave vertex to a convex vertex?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Please don't be surprised if there is a negative reaction. This site is not coding service. OTOH, someone may get a kick out of figuring out how to do it for you...

Comment: Do you mean [something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnQn.png)

Comment: @halirutan Yes, exactly! Are you able to put up the code as an answer?

Comment: @SandraRoss You know that you can *vote up* with the little arrow on my answer?

Comment: @halirutan I know, but I have to have at least $15$ points, sorry.

Comment: @SandraRoss Uhh, I think one could expect me to know this, but I didn't and you are correct. As soon as you ask a question that shows some more effort and is not only *gimme tha codez*, I will upvote it so that you gain some reputation.

Comment: @halirutan Once I'll get enough reputation, I upvote your answer. Thanks BTW for you answer.

Comment: No harm done, I have enough points for a life-time, but often new users don't know how the site's voting works. That's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

H3110 customer,

thank you for contacting StackExchange coding service. We propose the following solution to your urgent problem:

```
pts = Table[{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/5, 2 Pi/5}];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[pts], 
  Dashed, Red, 
  Line[{pts[[-1]], pts[[1]] - 2*(pts[[1]] - pts[[2]])*{1, 0}, pts[[2]]}]
}]
```

[image: high 5 gone]

Comment: It's really impossible to write a greeting at the beginning. Didn't know that SE removes them.

Comment: What an introduction.  Laugh; cry; vote.